# Update Multiple Nodes All Occurrence in XML Attibute

Tags: sql-server, xml

In a SQL Sever Database table, i have this
Here Student attribute is of type XML

### Table Class

```
ClassName  Student (XML)
A
B
C
```

Following is the structure of XML in EACH row

```
<Students>
 <Class>A</Class>
 <Student>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Hobbies>Music,Reading,Baseball</Hobbies>
 </Student>
 <Student>
  <Name>David</Name>
  <Hobbies></Hobbies>
 </Student>
 <Student>
  <Name>Sofiya</Name>
  <Hobbies>Surfing,Basketball</Hobbies>
 </Student>
</Students>
```

Here i want to update the Hobbies node by replace the ',' with a ';'. This i want to do for ALL ROWS and ALL OCCURRENCE of Hobbies in each row.

What should be my query to accomplish this?
I tried this, but instead of replacing the ',', its replacing the complete text with ';'

```
 declare @i int

 select top 1 @i = count(*) 
 from @table as o
     outer apply o.data.nodes('
            Students/
            Student[
                 Hobbies[contains(., ",")]]/Hobbies/text()                             
     ') as T(C) 
 order by count(*)
 print @i
 while @i > 0
 begin
     update @table set
         data.modify('
             replace value of 
             (
                  Students/
            Student[
                 Hobbies[contains(., ",")]]/Hobbies/text()     
             )[sql:variable("@i")][1]
             with ";"
        ') 

     set @i = @i - 1
 end;
```

Comment: Satheesh's solution below will not work as the above was just a sample xml based on my situation. The actual XML has other Nodes as well which might have a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you

```
declare @table table (classname varchar(10), students xml)
insert into @table values
('A','<Students>
 <Class>A</Class>
 <StudentA>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Hobbies>Music,Reading,Baseball</Hobbies>
 </StudentA>
 <StudentB>
    <Name>David</Name>
    <Hobbies></Hobbies>
 </StudentB>
 <StudentC>
    <Name>Sofiya</Name>
    <Hobbies>Surfing,Basketball</Hobbies>
 </StudentC>
</Students>');

SELECT * from @table
update @table
set students=convert(xml,replace(convert(varchar(max),students),',',';'))

select * from @table;
```

The Assumption is that no , appears anywhere other than hobbies